# Getting all rich results when scraping google

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to get all rich results from google when searching for restaurants data.

Right now i am using requests library and i can get basic info from request

```py
import requests
link='https://www.google.com/search?q=ellsworth+paris'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}


page = requests.get(link,headers=headers)
with open('out.html','w') as f:
    f.write(page.text)
```

This is what i get
[using GET request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2aZfa.png)

however when i search manually in browser i get more info like social media for example

[Manually from browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zZhL.png)

What should i add to the code to get all info ?

Comment: Chances are the remaining rich info is added by client-side JavaScript, so there's nothing simple you can just add. Also, Google is not meant to be scraped – they're quick to notice automated accesses and block your access.

Comment: I also tried to render javascript  using   Requests-HTML Render() , but no success yet